# Realm in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I am following a tutorial on Realm in react native

All the schemas are in `allSchemas.js`, based on the tutorial

```
 export const EVENTS_SCHEMA = 'events';
 export const EventsSchema = {
 name: EVENTS_SCHEMA,
 primaryKey: 'EventID',
 properties: {
 EventID: 'int',
 EventName: 'string',
 EventDate: 'string'
 }
 };
```

This is the App.js, now this is when  I get confused, in the database options a realm file was specified, am i to create a realm file before data can be stored and accessed or the realm file will automatically created once I specify it in my database options

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import { EventsSchema, EVENTS_SCHEMA } from './allSchemas';

const Realm = require('realm');
const databaseOptions = {
path: 'realmT4.realm',
schema: [EventsSchema],
schemaVersion: 0
};
```

Comment: When you write `Realm.open(databaseOptions)` Realm will attempt to make the a `realmT4.realm` (if it doesn't exist). If the file exists, Realm will just open that and use it.

Comment: Thanks @Dan for the clarification